# Why is the collections of all groups a variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

A variety is an equationally defined class of algebras. As I understand it equationally defined means defined by universally quantified equations, for example the variety of all semigroups could be defined as the class of algebras fullfilling
$x(yz) = (xy)z$.

But what about groups, there defining equations need existential quantification, the standard equations being: An algebra $(G, \cdot, 1)$ is a group iff

1) $\forall x,y,z : x(yz) = (xy)z$

2) $\forall x : 1\cdot x = x \cdot 1 = x$

3) $\forall x \exists y : x\cdot y = y\cdot x = 1$

The last equation (existence of inverses) I see as problematic, because it is not an universally quantified expression. So then group would not form a variety because they could not be defined by universally quantified equations, but in this article on the [Variety of groups](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variety_of_groups) the opposite is claimed.

> [...] Any variety of groups other than the variety of trivial groups and the variety of all groups [...]

So what did I missed here?

Comment: The "standard definition" is not the correct definition, but rather a characterization. Kind of sad that even today most books, lectures etc. make this wrong. A group is a tuple $(G,*,1,i)$ + properties, not a tuple $(G,*)$ or $(G,*,1)$ + properties. The correctness of this definition manifests for example when one considers group objects in other categories (topological groups, Lie groups, group schemes). Am I really the only one who wants to fight against these ad hoc "definitions" ...

Comment: thank you for pointing out! If you have concrete examples where the correct definition is superior I would be more happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We introduce a fourth operation: $\neg$, and use the equation
$$\forall x : x\cdot (\neg x) = 1 = (\neg x) \cdot x $$

Defining a new operation like so gives us the existence of an inverse without having the 'there exists' quantifier.