# How can I state the existence of inverses in order to define the variety of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

This question is related with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644251/why-is-the-collections-of-all-groups-a-variety) and [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941670/how-do-i-think-of-groups-as-a-universal-algebra), whose answers, however, I find unsatisfactory at the present moment.

My definition of "variety of algebras" comes from MacLane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*. The type $\langle \Omega, E \rangle$ of a variety of algebras is given by a graded set $\Omega$ of operators and a set $E$ of identities.

The grade of an operator is its *arity*. Given certain operators, one can form "derived" operators:

- if $\omega$ is an operator of arity $n$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are $n$ operators of arities $m_1,\ldots,m_n$, then $\omega(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m)$ is an operator of arity $m_1 + \cdots + m_n$
- if $\omega$ is an operator of arity $n$ and $f:\{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,m\}$ is any function, we can form a derived operator $\theta$ of arity $m$ by setting (in terms of variables) $\theta(x_1,\ldots,x_m) := \omega(x_{f(1)},\ldots,x_{f(n)})$

An identity is an ordered pair $\langle \lambda,\mu\rangle$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are derived operators of the same arity.

In every reference in the literature that I have found (and whose definitions of varieties of algebras are essentially the same as the one above), groups are the first/second example of a variety of algebras. In particular, as far as I understood, groups are considered varieties of algebras of the following type:
$$\Omega = \left\{e,\iota,\mu\right\} \qquad \text{and} \qquad E=\Big\{\langle\mu(\mu,id),\mu(id,\mu)\rangle,\ \langle\mu(e,id),id\rangle,\ \langle \mu(id,e),id\rangle,\ldots\Big\}$$
where $\mu$ (the compositon law) has arity $2$, $\iota$ (the inverse function) has arity $1$ and $e$ (the neutral element) has arity $0$ (the $1$-ary identity operator $id$ seems to be always included by default). The missing pair of relations in $E$ are those corresponding to the property of "being an inverse", which in terms of variables look like $\mu(x_1^{\phantom{1}},x_1^{-1}) = e = \mu(x_1^{-1},x_1^{\phantom{1}})$. Despite missing the diagonal operator, one can still mimic a $1$-ary operator, as the external ones in the latter equality, by considering the surjective function $f : \{1,2\} \to \{1\}$ and by setting
$$\theta(x_1) = \mu(x_{f(1)},\iota(x_{f(2)})).$$
However, I see no way to convert the latter into a $0$-ary operator without adding a whole family of $0$-ary operators (one for each variable $x$), which I don't like because it does not fit with the usual definitions of variety of groups. In addition, I don't like to consider $e$ as a non-defined-ary operator, so that it can be an operator of any arity ($1$, in particular), for the same reason. Finally, I see how to deal with the "group question" in categorical terms, but I would like to understand how this is handled in Universal Algebra.

Is there another explanation/solution/alternative for this issue that I don't see?

Comment: Instead of trying to convert a $1$-ary operator into a $0$-ary operator, how about converting $0$-ary operator into a $1$-ary operator?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I don't see how: I cannot use a function or a composition of "positive-ary" operators, I cannot define "negative-ary" operations (such as $G \to *$) and I don't like to say that $e$ is $1$-ary. Do you have another suggestion that I cannot see?

Comment: $e$ is $n$-ary. for $n=0$. In order to turn it into an $m$-ary operator, all you need (second derivation rule) is some $f\colon\{\,k\in\Bbb Z_{>0}\mid k\le n\,\}\to \{\,k\in\Bbb Z_{>0}\mid k\le m\,\}$. For $n=0$, the domain is the empty set and hence for each $m$ there exists one and only one such $f$ (let's call it $\operatorname{inc}_0^m$),and hence one and only one way to derive an $m$-ary operator from it. So the missing pair would be $\langle \mu\circ (id,\iota),e\circ\operatorname{inc}_0^1\rangle$ with both sides of arity $1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am not sure I understood your argument. Are you trying to define an $f:\{1\} \to \{\}$ that would allow us to construct a $1$-ary operator $\theta$ such that $$\theta(x_1) = e(x_{f(1)}) = e(*) = e$$ for every variable $x_1$? Please, notice also that the second derivation rule does not look like to be defined as you suggest. As far as I can deduce from MacLane (for example), both $m,n$ need to be greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Well there you're wrong then. @EnderWiggins

Comment: @AnginaSeng Could you argument a bit more, please? I simply took the definition from MacLane and I am trying to figure out from that how to handle the group case. [Here, page 124,](https://books.google.be/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=MXboNPdTv7QC&q=variety#v=snippet&q=variety&f=false) you may see my source.

Comment: Hagen has described for you in detail what to do. I would not "try" to define a function $\{1\}\to\emptyset$ as there is no such thing. But there is a function $\emptyset\to\{1\}$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I know that there is no such function. That's why I am asking to Hagen for further explanations. His function $\emptyset \to \{1\}$ does not exactly do the trick, as it would allow me to convert a $1$-ary operator into a $0$-ary operator. Thus, it would have been more precise to state that we are equating two $0$-ary operators with this trick, putting his function on the left-hand side instead that in front of $e$. In addition, I don't see this trick allowed by MacLane's definition, so my next question would be: could you please provide a reference for this argument?

Comment: By "on the left-hand side" I mean to use $\langle \mu \circ (id,\iota) \circ \text{inc}_0^1 ,e \rangle$ as identity in $E$ of $0$-ary operators, which however doesn't seem to me to be a correct conclusion.

Comment: BTW: May I ask to the downvoter to also comment on how I may improve the question, please?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe I understood your argument, at least. Imagining that $*$ plays the role of the "empty variable" and having the empty function $f:\{\} \to \{1\}$ I can construct a new $1$-ary operator $\theta$ by substitution which, on variables, behaves as $$\theta(x_1) = e(*).$$ Isn't it? In my previous comment I misread the direction of the $f$, true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of converting $\theta$ into a $0$-ary operator, you can convert $e$ into a $1$-ary operator.  Explicitly, consider the unique map $f:\emptyset\to\{1\}$.  Since $e$ is an operator of arity $0$, you can "relabel" its inputs via $f$ to get a derived operator $e_1$ of arity $1$.  The identity you want is then $\langle\theta,e_1\rangle$ (and the corresponding identity for multiplying in the opposite order).

Intuitively, what's going on here is that the identity $\mu(x_1,x_1^{-1})=e$ is an identity of operators of one variable, where the variable just happens to not appear on the right side.  But since it's an identity we want to be true for all values of $x_1$, we definitely want to consider both sides as functions of $x_1$.  Taking the constant $e$ and considering it as a constant function of one variable is exactly what relabelling its inputs by the map $f:\emptyset\to\{1\}$ does.